# Parameterizing docker exec psql -c commands

Tags: docker, parameter-passing, psql

I have this script with some commands like:

```
sudo docker exec $container psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $gisdb ;"
```

The `$container` parameter is no problem, but I cannot get the right value read with `$gisdb` parameter in the `CREATE DATABASE` command. Is it possible any other way or do I need to redesign this command or use hardcoded values?

Comment: What value is assigned to $gisdb variable? Does the command fail? If not, what name is the database created with?

Comment: better do not hardcode values. in the script, before sudo line, you can dump variables to your some log file, for example  date >>yourlogfile ; env >>yourlogfile  and reviev them.

Comment: In this specific case the name is gisdb also, but I want to parameterize the script, so I only have to change parametervalues on top of the script when running for new or other purposes (postgresql wise of course) ....

Answer (score 0):

### DB name

According to [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html), creating database requires name of the database

`CREATE DATABASE _`name`_`

So, `$gisdb` in your code - is the name of the created database.
You might hardcode this name, but you should exactly know - *which* name you' hardcode.

Because, generally, other services depends on DB name.
So, check the manual of your code.

### get rid of `sudo`

You can omit `sudo` before `docker` command.
Just add current user to the `docker` group:

```
usermod -aG docker $USER
```

And then, after login, you'll be able to run `docker` without `sudo`

Comment: Thanks for the "get rid of sudo"  tip. And as I understand of the first part of your post this create database command does not allow parameterized values as input?